# Android - Dynamic textViews - setMargins not applying?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

I'm trying to make a dynamic grid layout, it being API 10+ is the part that's been making it slow going. I tried to make it wrap automatically.. but in the end found it easier just to try to force it into a grid pattern using coordinates. This script was working by itself when I did the positioning at time of creation, but now I am trying to loop through each item as a sort. So if one item is deleted, they all float back into a grid without a hole in the middle.

Problem is, it seems the layout parameters are only applying to the last object.

Here's some base variables and onCreate setup:

```
int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;
int distStep = 130;
int leftPad = 20;
int numCols;
int baseID = 0;

android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
numCols = (int) (screenWidth - leftPad) / distStep;
int scrRemain = screenWidth - ((numCols * distStep) + leftPad);
distStep += (int) scrRemain / numCols;
```

Then on to the main function for adding:

```
public void addObjToLayout() {
    RelativeLayout relLay = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.mainWindow);
    for(int i = 1; i <= currQuantity; i++){
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setTextSize(40);
        tv.setId(baseID + i);
        tv.setPadding(24, 4, 24, 4);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0x110000FF);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(baseID + i));     //Val for debugging
        tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        relLay.addView(tv);
    }
    baseID += currQuantity;
    sortLayout();
  }
```

Then the sorting:

```
public void sortLayout() {
    int leftNum = 20;
    int topNum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= baseID; i++){
        TextView tv= (TextView) this.findViewById(baseID);
        MarginLayoutParams mp = new MarginLayoutParams(tv.getLayoutParams());
        mp.setMargins(leftNum, topNum, 0, 0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mp);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        leftNum += distStep;
        if(leftNum >= distStep * numCols){
            leftNum = leftPad;
            topNum += distStep;
        }
    }
  }
```

What I am getting is all the textViews pile up in the top left corner, except the last one which is positioned exactly where it should be. So it seems in my head, the params object isn't applying until the loop ends or something.. but logically I don't see why.

As I said, this worked when I set the params at the get go, problem is mass updating them all at once. I am pretty new to android, so I hope I'm not just doing something stupid.

Thanks for your time

Comment: If you are trying to make a grid layout why not just use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)?

Comment: When I tried to add that initially, it told me it wasn't kosher with my base API level (10). The docs say it's API 1, but Eclipse barks at me about compatibility.

Comment: That's odd. I have not personally used `GridView` yet so unfortunately I am of little help any further.

Comment: *smacks head* Just realized there's GridView (API 1) and GridLayout (API 14). I'm going to look into this more. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that actually. I will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started looking into GridView using an extended baseAdapter. Looks promising:

For more (see #2):
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 0):

Margin means it will set a gap between the previous view and current view.
When you add view1, view2 and view3 to grid layout and if you remove view2 at some point of time, then the margin for view3 is set according to view1. So, it won't leave empty space in place of view2. Instead of removing view2 at run time, set the background for view2 as null and set the text as empty as below.

```
textView.setBackground(null);
textView.setText("");
```

So that the view is still available but looks as deleted.

Comment: In the realm of possibility, but I am also planning on dessing up each textview with a positioned imageView and another textview label at it's corner. So it's not as simple.